# C# - Newtonsoft : Generic class for Client Response

Tags: c#, generics, json.net

After hours of attempts and research, I am asking for your help.

I am calling a public API which returns the same structure except for the datas returned.

For examples, the REST calls which retrieve stations and districts return those two JSON answers :

Stations response :

```
"response" : {
    "status": { "@attributes": {"code": "0", "message": "OK"} },
    "data" : { 
        "station": [{
            "number": "stationId",
            "name": "stationName",
            "address": "stationAddress",
            "state": "1",
            "latitude": "stationLat",
            "longitude": "stationLong",
            "slotsavailable": "10",
            "bikesavailable": "20",
            "pos": "0",
            "district": "stationDistrict",
            "lastupdate": "2016-03-28T11:47:08+02:00"
        }, {...}, ...]}
}
```

Districts response :

```
"response" : {
    "status": { "@attributes": {"code": "0", "message": "OK"} },
    "data" : { "district": [{"id": "districtId", "name": "districtName"}, {...}, ...] }
}
```

I am using a .NET 4.5/C# solution with Newtonsoft.Json to execute the call.
I want to make the object, mapped to the client response, generic so the execution of the call will be made as follow :

```
var result = await client.Execute<Response<ApiResponseDistrict>>(request);
var result = await client.Execute<Response<ApiResponseStation>>(request);
```

My first attempt was to make a non generic call (create a full object by returned datas) which was a success.

My second attempt was to created a generic object so I made the following classes using the `JsonProperty` of the library Newtonsoft :

```
public class ApiResponse<T>
{
    [JsonProperty("response")]
    public Response<T> Response { get; set; }
}

public class Response<T>
{
    [JsonProperty("status")]
    public Status Status { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public Data<T> Data { get; set; }
}

public class Data<T>
{
    public T ResponseData { get; set; }
}

public class ApiResponseDistrict
{
    [JsonProperty("district")]
    public List<District> Districts { get; set; }
}

public class District
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

At this point, when I am executing the call the object Response is valorized and also its property Status with the value waited but the property Data is never valorized (null).

My third attempt was to continue on the second attempt but using the `JsonObject` of the Newtonsoft library which it's given (with the same result) :

```
[JsonObject("district")]
public class ApiResponseDistrict
{
    public List<District> Districts { get; set; }
}
```

As I am new to Newtonsoft, I would like to know if it is possible to use generic classes, as I am trying to do, to mapped the object returned by the call or I have to create a complete object for each "data" returned ?

Thank you for your answer and explanations or clues for me to find the answer !

Comment: What's the definition for ResponseData and Status classes?

Comment: Status class is a class I created in the same way as Data class. ResponseData is just the name of the property with the Type T which is in the case of my example ApiResponseDistrict.

Comment: Are those the actual responses, because neither of those is valid JSON.

Comment: @KennethK. My bad, it was a bad copy/paste I edit my message with the correct JSON which are returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Response<T>
{
    [JsonProperty("status")]
    public Status Status { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public Data<T> Data { get; set; }
}

public class Data<T>
{
    public T ResponseData { get; set; }
}
```

This adds another layer between the data, so a response would look like this:

```json
{
    "Status": …,
    "Data": {
        "ResponseData": {
            <The actual type T>
        }
    }
}
```

Instead, you want to remove that `ResponseData` level:

```
public class Response<T>
{
    [JsonProperty("status")]
    public Status Status { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public T Data { get; set; }
}
```

So for example, for the JSON above, you would have a `StationResponseData` class:

```
public class StationResponseData
{
    public List<Station> Stations
    { get; set; }
}
```

And then you would deserialize the JSON as `Response<StationResponseData>`. The `Station` class would then contain those properties for `number`, `name`, `address`, etc.

Comment: Thank you @poke, it was indeed the ResponseData level which was bothering ! I was thinking that the level was just added when you specify the JsonProperty but it seems that it isn't.